# How to destroy previous instance of window?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button with a click function like this

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title: 'We want your Feedback!',
                            cls: 'Hub-feedback-form',
                            //height: 320,
                            width: 300,
                            layout: 'fit',
                            closable: true,
                            closeAction: 'destroy',
                            items: [form]
                            
                        });
win.show();
winVisible++ //winVisible is a global variable declared as 0.
if(winVisible % 2==0)
{
win.hide();
}
```

But what is happening is it is creating multiple instances of win, so everytime an insstance remains, how to modify the code so that every open instance of win gets removed. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `win.close()`, it will remove the component and destroy it.

Comment: I want to hide the window on second click of button, but one instance of win remains no matter what I do.

Comment: Hiding does not destroy a window, only makes it invisible. If you call `destroy`, it will be destroyed as an ExtJS component, but that does not mean that the variable `win` will be `null` or `undefined`. Even destroyed components can be still available from JS code, see for example [`destroyed`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#property-destroyed) property of `Ext.window.Window`.

Comment: Eventually JS garbage collection will take care of unreferenced objects.

Comment: yeah, i get it, but how to hide that window component, means the window will retain the values(if any) inserted into the form

Comment: If you keep `win` variable and don't create the window if it already exists (`if (!win) {win=Ext.create...}`), and `form` variable holds the form, it should retain state if you `hide` and after `show` it.

Comment: if I dont create the window, it says win is undefined

Comment: got it, i gave the window an id and set it to hide and it got hidden. Thanks :)